# What does it mean for something to be 'in shear'?

Tags: civil-engineering, stresses

When I was first introduced to 'shear stress' it was using the concept of a beam, this beam was under tension and we determined a value for shear stress for different planes on the beam. As we expect the principal normal stress is along the axial surface area.

However, when discussing structures a lot of the time (for example trusses and some arches) we are told that all the elements are under 'no shear' or that they are under either tension or compression.

If it is possible to resolve shear stresses relative to certain planes in the object, i.e for certain planes in the object the axial force acts as a shear force, how can we say these elements are under 'no shear'?

Is it that we draw a distinction between shear stresses along certain planes and external shear forces?

Comment: shear means that theres tension between the coplanar planes. uniform compression does not neccesitate shear since tho loading is same everywhere.

Comment: TLTR: a quick google search gives: https://coefs.charlotte.edu/mwhelan3/files/2010/10/ICD_Single_V_Double_Shear.pdf

Comment: Truss usually is made of slender members with negligible weight compared to other loadings, and it is often loaded at the joints only, so the member shear stress is ignored for simplicity.

Comment: At a fundamental level, doesn't shear mean deviatoric stress on an infinitesimal element, as opposed to hydrostatic?

Answer (score 3):

*Internal* shear stresses result from externally-applied tension or compression stresses when they get trigonometrically *resolved* along the directions of certain crystallographic planes in the solid member. So a structural member that is externally stressed in tension will ultimately yield in *shear* along the plane direction of the *maximum (critical) resolved shear stress* which is usually at 45 degrees to the direction of the externally applied tension force.

*External* shear stresses are those that are applied to the stressed member in such a manner that if we take a transverse slice through the stressed member, the forces on the opposite cut faces of the member act to rub those cut faces sideways relative to one another.

Comment: So I should understand that the elements are under *external shear* such as a beam under bending as opposed to a beam under tension?

Comment: When discussing members 'in shear' we are discussing members where there is shear stresses casued by an external shear force? A force which causes *external* shear stresses?

Answer (score 0):

When considering shear stress in beams and structures, it is essential to differentiate between shear stresses along certain planes within the object and external shear forces acting on the object.

In the context of beams, shear stress refers to the stress component that is coplanar with a material cross-section and arises from the shear force acting parallel to the cross-section. This type of shear stress is relevant when analyzing the internal behaviour of beams, as it provides information about the distribution of stresses within the beam. Calculating shear stress at different beam planes allows you to determine the shear stress distribution across its cross-section.
On the other hand, when discussing structures like trusses and arches, the statement that elements are under "no shear" generally refers to the external shear forces acting on the structure as a whole, rather than the internal shear stresses within the elements. In these cases, the focus is often on the overall stability and equilibrium of the structure, rather than the distribution of stresses within individual elements. The statement that there is "no shear" means that the sum of the external shear forces acting on the structure is zero, ensuring that the structure remains in equilibrium.

**Hence, the concept of "no shear" in structures refers to the external shear forces being in balance, ensuring overall stability. However, within individual elements like beams, shear stress can still exist and is important for understanding the internal stress distribution.**